# R Collapse rows by ID and append two observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that looks like this.

```
ID      SKU       Type   Option
238887  ALTH2446  Black  23608910
238887  ALTH2446  White  23608923
```

And I want it to look like this. I really don't care which row is kept as long as the ID2 field is right.

```
ID      SKU       Type   Option   ID2
238887  ALTH2446  Black  23608910 ALTH2446-23608910-23608923
```

I've tried this, but it's not outputting the ID2 field correctly.

```
data %>% 
       group_by(ID) %>% 
       summarise(ID2 = paste(ID,Option, collapse="-"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about losing the Type and Option columns:

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID, SKU) %>%
  summarise(ID2 = paste(Option, collapse="-")) %>%
  mutate(ID2 = paste(SKU, ID2, sep="-"))
```